# DB2 Stored Procedure Returning Too many rows

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I have an extremely simple stored procedure to find tables in a specific schema based on my schema and table parameters.

The problem is the stored procedure returns ALL of the rows for the table.

- It ignores my second parameter (table_name)
- I can misspell the table_name parameter and the procedure returns all the rows.
- If I misspell the schema parameter it will not return any rows.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance. Stored procedure is below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FINDTABLECOLUMNS 
(IN SCHEMA VARCHAR(25), IN TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(25))
LANGUAGE SQL
READS SQL DATA
RESULT SETS 1

BEGIN

  DECLARE COLUMN_TABLE_LIST CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CALLER FOR
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( ORDER BY TABLE_NAME , ORDINAL_POSITION ) AS # 
       ,TABLE_NAME
       ,COLUMN_NAME
       ,SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME
       ,DATA_TYPE
       ,LENGTH
       ,COLUMN_TEXT
  FROM QSYS2 . SYSCOLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = UPPER ( SCHEMA ) AND TABLE_NAME = UPPER ( TABLE_NAME )
  FOR READ ONLY ;

  OPEN COLUMN_TABLE_LIST ;
END
```

Comment: Do you need ROW_NUMBER() if you already have ORDINAL_POSITION?  SCALE is often handy in such queries, for the number of decimal places on (packed) decimal or (zoned) numeric columns.

Comment: You need to take into account the limits of the object: schema is a varchar(128) the same as the tablename. Also, the if the schema is less than 8 chars it will add extra spaces to fit. This is in LUW, I do not know for other platforms

Comment: http://angocadb2.blogspot.com/2015/07/esquemas-y-nombres-de-usuario-en-el.html

Comment: Using ROW_NUMBER() was my cheesy of getting a column count, because I don't know how else to do it with DB2 yet. I'm grew up on MSSQL so I'm in a totally new world. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because the columnname and parametername are equal. You can solve it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FINDTABLECOLUMNS 
(IN SCHEMA VARCHAR(25), IN TABLE_NAME_PAR VARCHAR(25))
LANGUAGE SQL
READS SQL DATA
RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN
DECLARE COLUMN_TABLE_LIST CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CALLER FOR
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( ORDER BY TABLE_NAME , ORDINAL_POSITION ) AS # 
   ,TABLE_NAME
   ,COLUMN_NAME
   ,SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME
   ,DATA_TYPE
   ,LENGTH
   ,COLUMN_TEXT
FROM QSYS2 . SYSCOLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = UPPER ( SCHEMA ) AND TABLE_NAME = UPPER ( TABLE_NAME_PAR )
FOR READ ONLY ;
OPEN COLUMN_TABLE_LIST ;
END
```

Comment: Personally,  I would probably just put an `@` on the front of my parameter names.

Comment: Also, `SCHEMA` is a reserved word and should not be used for a parameter or variable name. Also, consider that the table and schema names in the catalog might be in lowercase.

Comment: @mustaccio Avoiding reserved names is one of the reasons behind my "@" prefix comment, but I should have explained, eh?  ;-)

Comment: Luc...Thanks a mil! I had a feeling it would be a forehead slapper, as mustaccio and Warren pointed out. Idk how I missed something so obvious. I like Warren's idea of adding "@" to the front of variable names. It makes it easier to identify the variables. Another thing I noticed is System i Navigator (which is what I'm using) does not show color coding, so I don't know when I'm using reserved words and when I'm not. I'll just have to look out for that. Thanks again everyone!